# Postfix - route mail based on Sender/Connecting IP?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp

I would like to configure my Postfix mail relay to route mails received from another server on my network to a specific upstream mail server. There are a wide variety of recipient and reply-to addresses set, so I'm unable to configure a standard transport rule based on domain name. I seem to be finding conflicting information in documentation/alternative sources, but I've not found anything that positives confirms for sure whether this is possible.

Does anybody know if there's a way I could achieve the equivalent of something like the following rule?

```
192.168.0.50/32 smtp:[smtp.example.com]
```

Thanks.